# My App's RecycleViews don't have a scrollbar,but it works on a new project

Tags: android

I found this code does't work in my Project.

`android:scrollbars="vertical"`

But if i set this to a new **DEMO**,it works.
I think it's about App styles or something in `build.gradle`,but i try many methods and it's just didn't work(like copy the Application styls from my project to the new project and apply it,it still works),any one else has this problem?
this is my `build.gradle` code:

```
 android {
compileSdkVersion COMPILE_SDK_VERSION as int
buildToolsVersion BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.haixue.app.android.HaixueAcademy.h4"
    minSdkVersion MIN_SDK_VERSION as int
    targetSdkVersion TARGET_SDK_VERSION as int
    versionCode 3210
    versionName "3.2.1beta"
    multiDexEnabled true 
    resConfigs "zh"

    resValue("string", "growingio_project_id", "8701f2e2e096a888")
    resValue("string", "growingio_url_scheme",       "growing.42190e827fb47099")

    ndk {
        abiFilters "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a"
    }
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}

aaptOptions {
    additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
}

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/MANIFEST.MF'
    exclude 'META-INF/maven/com.squareup.okio/okio/pom.properties'
    exclude 'META-INF/maven/com.squareup.okio/okio/pom.xml'
}

lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
    xmlReport false
    htmlReport true
    htmlOutput file("$project.buildDir/reports/lint/lint-result.html")
    xmlOutput file("$project.buildDir/reports/lint/lint-result.xml")
}
signingConfigs {
    release {
        storeFile file("../docs/haixue.keystore")
        storePassword "123456"
        keyAlias "highso"
        keyPassword "123456"
    }
    debug {
        storeFile file("../docs/haixue.keystore")
        storePassword "123456"
        keyAlias "highso"
        keyPassword "123456"
    }
}


walle {
    apkOutputFolder = new File("${project.buildDir}/outputs/channels");

    apkFileNameFormat = '${appName}-${channel}-${buildType}-v${versionName}.apk';

    channelFile = new File("${project.getProjectDir()}/channel")
}

buildTypes {
    debug {
        debuggable true
        minifyEnabled false
        shrinkResources false
        testCoverageEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }

    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        zipAlignEnabled true
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}


applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        def outputFile = output.outputFile
        if (outputFile != null && outputFile.name.endsWith('.apk')) {
            def fileName = outputFile.name.replace(".apk", "-${defaultConfig.versionName}.apk")
            output.outputFile = new File(outputFile.parent, fileName)
        }
    }
}

//JNI
sourceSets {
    main {
        jni.srcDirs = []
        jniLibs.srcDir(['libs'])
    }
}

dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}

repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}
}

 dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile project(':RtmpResourceLib')
compile project(':imagepicker')
compile project(':viewPagerlibrary')
compile project(':SlidingMenu')
compile project(':treeviewlist')
compile project(':NodeView')
compile files('libs/jcore-android-1.1.6.jar')
compile files('libs/jpush-android-3.0.8.jar')
compile files('libs/TalkFunSDK.jar')
compile files('libs/alipaySingle-20170510.jar')
compile(name: 'alicloud-android-feedback-3.1.1', ext: 'aar')
compile files('libs/alicloud-android-utils-1.0.3.jar')
compile files('libs/utdid4all-1.1.5.3_proguard.jar')
compile files('libs/alicloud-android-monitor-2.5.1.1_for_bc_proguard.jar')
//noinspection GradleCompatible
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
//compile 'com.tencent.bugly:crashreport:2.6.5' crashreport_upgrade
compile 'com.tencent.bugly:crashreport_upgrade:latest.release'
compile 'com.tencent.bugly:nativecrashreport:latest.release'
compile 'com.growingio.android:vds-android-agent:1.0.3@aar'
compile 'com.umeng.analytics:analytics:latest.integration'
compile 'com.tencent.mm.opensdk:wechat-sdk-android-with-mta:1.0.2'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
compile 'com.github.Aspsine:SwipeToLoadLayout:1.0.4'
compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.0'
compile 'com.lzy.net:okgo:2.1.4'
compile 'com.github.hackware1993:MagicIndicator:1.5.0'
compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
compile 'com.zhy:autolayout:1.4.5'
compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.3'
compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:5.0'
compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-core:5.0'
compile 'com.meituan.android.walle:library:1.1.3'
compile 'com.zhy:flowlayout-lib:1.0.3'
compile 'com.scwang.smartrefresh:SmartRefreshLayout:1.0.3'
compile 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:r2.5.2'
compile 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-hls:r2.5.2'
debugCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.5.3'
releaseCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5.3'
compile 'com.kyleduo.switchbutton:library:1.4.6'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out
       @android:color/transparent
SomeOthers set this in our App's Style ,this code make the ScrollBar transparent.